What TV show or movie did The Late Show use to humorously represent Russia's reaction to Trump's re-election?
The November 6, 2024 episode of The Late Show with Stephen Colbert featured a comedy segment that humorously illustrated various countries' reactions to Donald Trump's re-election. The segment incorporated pop culture clips from TV shows, movies, and video games, featuring a Harry Potter scene for England and the Swedish Chef for Sweden.
I'm trying to identify the clip used for Russia's reaction, which showed men in military uniform performing the Prisiadki (Russian squat-and-kick dance).




Can anyone identify the TV show or movie the clip was from?

This is the 'Soldier's Dance' (1965) by the Alexandrov Ensemble.

The music here has the same name - "Soldier's dance" and was written
by Vladimir Alexandrov, the brother of Boris Alexandrov and the
Director and the conductor of the Orchestra, specially for this dance.
This rare and historic program was filmed on location of "Sparrow
Hills" (Vorobiovy Gory) in Moscow in the former Soviet Union.
The brilliant Ensemble consisted of about 200 entertainers including a
choir and choreographic troupe, who traveled the front lines,
entertaining Soviet troops by performing more than 1500 concerts
during World War II.




Although it was published contemporaneously in the Soviet Union (via TV shows and the like), the clip on the Stephen Colbert show is likely taken from YouTube, which itself is cropped from Kultur: Soviet Army Chorus and Dance Ensemble (2008)
